# Why is my sass mixin compiling to one property per selector?

Tags: html, css, sass

Recently I am trying to use sass to create a mixin/function that help me with my responsive design, but I got stuck on a problem for the past three days and I have tried many different kinds of approach but nothing works.

The problem I am facing is when sass compiled, it outputs something like this, with one style per selector, which I don't want:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 3840px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 7rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  h1 {
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  h1 {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 3840px) {
  h1 {
    margin-top: 1.8rem;
  }
}
```

**I want the output to be like this:**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 3840px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 7rem;
    margin-top: 1.8rem;
  }
}
```

**This is my Sass file**:

```
// function
@function size-number($base-size, $new-size) {
    @if $new-size != 0 {
        @return $new-size;
    } @else {
        @return $base-size;
    }
}



// mixin
@mixin break-points-size ($properties) {
    $PROPERTIES: $properties;
    @each $PROPERTY-KEY, $PROPERTY-VALUE in $PROPERTIES {
        $SIZE-NUMBERS: map-get($PROPERTY-VALUE, "size" );

        $BREAK-POINTS: (
            "screen1080": (
                "break-point": "1920px",
                "base-size":  size-number(1,nth($SIZE-NUMBERS, 1))
            ),
            "screen1440": (
                "break-point": "2560px",
                "base-size": size-number(2,nth($SIZE-NUMBERS, 2))
            ),
            "screen2160": (
                "break-point": "3840px",
                "base-size": size-number(3,nth($SIZE-NUMBERS, 3))
            )
        );


        $INDIV-PROPERTY-KEY: $PROPERTY-KEY;
        $VALUE-NUMBERS: map-get($PROPERTY-VALUE, "value" );

        
        @each $BREAK-POINT-KEY, $BREAK-POINT-VALUE in $BREAK-POINTS {
            $INDIV-BREAK-POINT: map-get($BREAK-POINT-VALUE, "break-point");
            $INDIV-BASE-SIZE: map-get($BREAK-POINT-VALUE, "base-size");
            @media only screen and (min-width:$INDIV-BREAK-POINT) {
                #{$INDIV-PROPERTY-KEY}: $VALUE-NUMBERS * $INDIV-BASE-SIZE;
            }
        }        
    }
};





*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


h1{
    @include break-points-size(("font-size":("value": 2rem,"size": (2,3,3.5)),"margin-top":("value": 1rem,"size": (0.8,1,1.8))));


}
```

I just can't find which part I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a mixin for breakpoints you may find useful. It solves the problem of having multiple copies of the same media query for every different property.

```css
@mixin breakpoint($map) {
    $query: '';
    @if map-has-key($map, media) {$query: append($query, '#{map-get($map, media)} and');}
    @if map-has-key($map, min-width) {$query: append($query, '(min-width: #{map-get($map, min-width)})');}
    @if map-has-key($map, min-width) and map-has-key($map, max-width) {$query: append($query, "and");}
    @if map-has-key($map, max-width) {$query: append($query, '(max-width: #{map-get($map, max-width)})');}
    @media #{$query} {@content;}
}
```

Use it like this:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    @include breakpoint((min-width: 860px)) {
        some-property: someValue;
        some-other-property: soneValue;
    }
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    @include breakpoint((min-width: 860px, max-width: 1000px)) {
        some-property: someValue;
    }
}
```